# ISO_WEEK not supported for DatePart with datetime

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

When I execute the statement

```
select DATEADD(iso_week,10-1,DATEADD(yy,2018-1900,0))
```

(the values 10 and 2018 are in productive variables)

in SQL SErver, I get the error (translated from german to english)

The DatePart-Value ISO_WEEK is not supported of the Date-Function DateAdd for the datetime-Datatype.

Can someone help me, what there is wrong?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, `ISO_WEEK` isn't a valid input for the first parameter of `DATEADD`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) tells you what options you have.

Comment: oh - thank you for your hint. These was a copy-mistake from datepart.